# How to apply config transformations to an external config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config, transformation

I can't find an example of my question on the web and was wondering if anybody knew a solution.  Basically, if on our web.config we point to another file, like so:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections />
  <appSettings file="AppSettings.config">
</configuration>
```

then how do we apply transformations to that external file?

Basically, I want to create an AppSettings.config, AppSettings.Debug.config, AppSettings.Release.config and have a transformation run over it...  Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance,

Sergio

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are few workarounds:

> **Workaround 1**

- Write `AppSettings.Debug.config`, `AppSettings.Release.config` with full values (not with transform attributes)
- In your `web.config`, using transformation, substitute with the appropriate file:

***`web.debug.config`***

```
<appSettings file="AppSettings.debug.config" 
             xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(file)"/>
```

***`web.release.config`***

```
<appSettings file="AppSettings.release.config" 
             xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(file)"/>
```

Its less than ideal, kinda defeats the purpose of transforms but may be appropriate based on one's situation than using something like SlowCheetah.

> **Workaround 2**

Use `TransformXml` build task to transform your files during build as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952091/msbuild-transform-one-config-few-times) and [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-custom-webconfig-0)

Comment: With workaround 1 I wouldn't have separate AppSettings.config on the deployed version, right? The "preset" AppSettings.Release.config would be merged into the main web.config.

Comment: You'd still need `AppSettings.release.config` to be deployed. The settings aren't ***pulled*** inside the `web.config`, rather loaded from the file that you point to.

Answer (score 9):

There's a Visual Studio plugin project called [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) that takes the idea of transformations and allows you to apply it to files other than web.config, I haven't used it but I think it'll do what you want to do. Scott Hanselman did a [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) on it.

Answer (score 5):

Workaround 1 in the accepted answer put me on the right track, but didn't work as is because the transformation isn't quite right. The correct transformation is just

```
<appSettings file="AppSettings.debug.config" 
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
```

I had to remove xdt:Locator="Match(file)" so that the file attribute itself would change.  [Web Config Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) explains that Match(key) will locate the element to change, but will only change the other elements of the node, not the locator/match key itself. There will be only one appSetting per config file, so we don't need to locate a particular instance.

(I don't have enough reputation to comment on the accepted answer, so I posted this as another answer.)