# msbuild transform one config few times

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, web-config, configuration-files

I have next config in my Web.config file

```
<Target Name="UpdateWebConfigForProjectsBeforeRun">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToTransofm Include="ProjectsDeployBin\Web.*.$(Configuration).config"/>      
    </ItemGroup>    
    <Message Text="Transform file: %(FilesToTransofm.Identity)" />
    <TransformXml Source="web.config"
                  Transform="%(FilesToTransofm.Identity)"
                  Destination="web.config" />
  </Target>
```

What i am trying to do its get all configs from ProjectsDeployBin directory and apply each file to main web.config.

After first transformation main web.config locked by msbuild.

So how can i fix this issue? Is there any other way to transform my web.config by collection of files?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've noticed, the TransformXml task shipped with Visual Studio 2010 has a bug that leaves the source file locked.

To work around that, you can make a temporary copy of your source file before each transformation.
Since you'll then be executing multiple tasks for each transform file (copy and transform), you'll need to switch to [Target Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228229(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of [Task Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171474%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FilesToTransofm Include="ProjectsDeployBin\Web.*.$(Configuration).config"/>      
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="UpdateWebConfigForProjectsBeforeRun"
        Inputs="@(FilesToTransofm)"
        Outputs="%(Identity).AlwaysRun">
  <Message Text="Transform file: %(FilesToTransofm.Identity)" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="web.config"
        DestinationFiles="web.pre-%(FilesToTransofm.Filename).temp.config" />
  <TransformXml Source="web.pre-%(FilesToTransofm.Filename).temp.config"
                Transform="%(FilesToTransofm.Identity)"
                Destination="web.config" />
</Target>
```

*From a quick test, it looks like this bug is fixed in Visual Studio 2012, but I'm not able to find a reference / source that documents that, and the [original Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562200/transformxml-task-locks-config-file-identified-in-source-attribute) isn't viewable anymore.*